# Running a command on startup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, server

I want to run this command on my ubuntu server installation on startup:

```
~/factorio/bin/x64/factorio --start-server-load-latest --server-settings ~/factorio/data/server-settings.json
```

I tried putting this code in the `/etc/rc.local` directory:

```
~/factorio/bin/x64/factorio --start-server-load-latest --server-settings ~/factorio/data/server-settings.json || exit 1
exit 0
```

And the command doesn't run on startup. I know that the command runs when I type it into the command line, but it won't run for some reason when I put it in the `/etc/rc.local` file. Can anyone tell me where the error is in my code or another way that I could get this command to run on boot?

Answer (score 0):

Open crontab.

```
 sudo crontab -e
```

Then try adding you command as root to the bottom.(use nano editor).

```
 @reboot root ~/factorio/bin/x64/factorio --start-server-load-latest --server-settings ~/factorio/data/server-settings.json
```

Note that this will run under root so you will need to change the path of every file from '~/call' to '/full/path/to/file'